# How to get groupwise Email Ids in google?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-groups, google-groups-api

We are using Google for corporate since last 5 years. There have been many dozens google groups created by different site/business division/local administrators. Now we need to know, for each employee, which all groups he is a part of. Does google provide any API to fetch this details ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_domain_groups) has a function to **Retrieve all groups for a domain or the account**. Here's a part in the docs that I think is what you are specifically aiming for:

> **All groups for the account** — Use the `customer` argument with either `my_customer` or the account's `customerId` value. As an account administrator, use the string my_customer to represent your account's `customerId`. If you are a reseller accessing a resold customer's account, use the resold account's `customerId`. For the `customerId` value use the account's primary domain name in the Retrieve all users in a domain operation's request. The resulting response has the `customerId` value.